# Bootstrap 3 mobile menu not working properly

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Everything on my bootstrap wp site works great except for the mobile menu. It collapses but then you can't click on it to go back to the hamburger menu when it has collapsed. I've noticed that this is covered here: [Bootstrap wordpress mobile menu not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509236/bootstrap-wordpress-mobile-menu-not-working?answertab=oldest#tab-top) but the answer isn't quite clear to me.

The URL is http://www.jfmobilemechanics.com.au

Here is the nav code:

```html
<body id="page-top" class="index">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top pull-right">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>"><?php bloginfo('name')?></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<?php /* Primary navigation */
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'       => 'primary',
    'depth'      => 2,
    'container'  => false,
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav pull-right',
    'walker'     => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
?>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</body>
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be including bootstraps js two times so the click event on the menu button gets triggered two times, closing the menu when trying to open it.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you for looking into it. Really appreciate it. It was pretty tedious trying to work out the cause.

Comment: Glad it helped. And if you don't mind you can accept it as an answer so the question gets resolved.